# How to custom exit kiosk mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to exit kiosk mode in my Flutter application after user writes my custom PIN. I do not want to have PIN code on my device.

I found on pub.dev package called kiosk_mode: "https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_mode"

I can not see if there is option to exit my kiosk mode using my custom widget.

I am thinking about overriding this call:

```dart
Future<bool?> stopKioskMode() => _channel.invokeMethod<bool>('stopKioskMode');
```

I want to show some custom PIN code, and after user writes it only then I want to exit my app

How to create extension of method "stopKioskMode" there is no class that I am able to extend